# BigDecimal compareTo not working as expected

Tags: java, bigdecimal

According to the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) for `BigDecimal`, the `compareTo` function does not account for the scale during comparison.

Now I have a test case that looks something like this:

```
BigDecimal result = callSomeService(foo);
assertTrue(result.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.7)) == 0); //this does not work
assertTrue(result.equals(new BigDecimal(0.7).setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))); //this works
```

The value I'm expecting the function to return is `0.7` and has a scale of 10. Printing the value shows me the expected result. But the `compareTo()` function doesn't seem to be working the way I think it should.

What's going on here?

Comment: You're *expecting* the value to be 0.7, but are you *sure*?  Have you tried making callSomeService simply return new BigDecimal(0.7)?

Comment: @CPerkins Yup, quite sure about that. I printed the result and the `equals` method was also working. Anyway, the problem is solved :)

Comment: This one also puzzled me, until i understood that i was creating a BigDecimal from a DOUBLE... :-\

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`new BigDecimal(0.7)` does **not** represent 0.7.

It represents 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 (exactly).

The reason for this is that the `double` literal `0.7` doesn't represent 0.7 exactly.

If you need **precise** `BigDecimal` values, you **must** use the `String` constructor (actually *all* constructors that don't take `double` values will work).

Try `new BigDecimal("0.7")` instead.

The [JavaDoc of the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) has some related notes:

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The `String` constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing `new BigDecimal("0.1")` creates a `BigDecimal` which is *exactly* equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally recommended that the [`String` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) be used in preference to this one.
> 3. When a `double` must be used as a source for a `BigDecimal`, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the `double` to a `String` using the [`Double.toString(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) method and then using the [`BigDecimal(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) constructor. To get that result, use the `static` [`valueOf(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) method.

So to summarize: If you want to create a `BigDecimal` with a fixed decimal value, use the `String` constructor. If you *already have* a `double` value, then [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) will provide a more intuitive behaviour than using [`new BigDecimal(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29).