# Why does new BigDecimal("0.015").compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.015)) return -1?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why does `new BigDecimal("0.015").compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.015))` return -1?
If I expect those two to be equal, is there an alternative way to compare them?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058984/bigdecimal-compareto-not-working-as-expected?rq=1

Comment: Would be better to make use of `new BigDecimal("0.015")`. For the reason that @Reimeus pointed on in his answer.

Comment: You could do the comparison the same way you would compare two doubles that resulted from different calculations - accept as equal anything that is close enough, for the purposes of your program.

Comment: because `0.015` is already not `0.015` when it is passed to BigDecimal, while `"0.015"` is parsed by `BigDecimal` itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `double` cannot exactly represent the value `0.015`. The closest value it can represent in its 64 binary bits is `0.01499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375`. The constructor [`new BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) is designed to preserve the precise value of the `double` argument, which can never be exactly `0.015`. Hence the result of your comparison.

*However*, if you display that `double` value, for example by:

```
System.out.println(0.01499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375);
```

it outputs `0.015` – which hints at a workaround. [Converting a `double` to a `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) chooses the shortest decimal representation needed to distinguish it from other possible `double` values.

Thus, if you create a `BigDecimal` from the `double`'s `String` representation, it will have a value more as you expect. This comparison is true:

```
new BigDecimal(Double.toString(0.015)).equals(new BigDecimal("0.015"))
```

In fact, the method [**`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) exists for exactly this purpose, so you can shorten the above to:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.015).equals(new BigDecimal("0.015"))
```

You should use the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor only if your purpose is to preserve the precise binary value of the argument. Otherwise, call `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, whose documentation says:

> This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`.

*Or*, use a `String` if you can and avoid the subtleties of `double` entirely.

Answer (score 20):

Due to the imprecise nature of floating point arithmetic, they're not exactly equal

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.015));
```

displays

```
0.01499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
```

Comment: Whereas `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.015"));` displays exactly 0.015.

Comment: If I expect ```new BigDecimal(0.015)``` to be equal to ```new BigDecimal("0.015")```, how can I compare them?

Comment: you should not expect them to be equal. whenever you use floating point arithmetic you should be aware that these kind of errors will occur.

Comment: @Glide you can always set the precision of your `BigDecimal` ie, `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.015).setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));` prints `0.015`

Comment: @Glide: If you expect new BigDecimal(0.015) to be equal to new BigDecimal("0.015"), then you should expect to be wrong, and you should expect that you'll have to expect something different.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Er.....I (as a non-Java programmer and thus an outsider) was under the impression that the *entire point* of `BigDecimal` is to accurately represent *decimal numbers*. Heck, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) even says *arbitrary precision* decimal numbers! If `0.015` is not represented in a unique way, how the heck is the `BigDecimal` class supposed to be useable??

Comment: @KyleStrand: The point is that you have to pass _decimal numbers in_, and writing `new BigDecimal(0.015)` stores `0.015` as a `double` -- _not_ a decimal number -- before it even gets to `BigDecimal`.  You have to pass it in as a `String`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Well, that actually makes complete sense, and I withdraw my objection.

Comment: I guess my only complaint, then, is that `BigDecimal` even provides a constructor from `double` in the first place.

Comment: @KyleStrand I think it's logical to provide the constructor. You might need to interoperate with numbers stored in that form. However, you need to know what kind of precision you expect from the number, and you should probably call `setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` with an appropriate number of decimal places before actually trying to do any math. Maybe you would be more accepting of the constructor if it was `BigDecimal(double, int, int)` where the second argument specified how many decimal places to keep and the third was a rounding mode?

Comment: @jpmc26 Absolutely--I think an explicit constructor like that would be a much better API (though the third argument should be some kind of `enum` rather than `int`). Even providing the same behavior currently provided by the `double` constructor inside of an explicitly-named `static` factory-function, such as `BigDecimal::CreateFromNumericPrimitive(double)` would be better, because it would remind users that they're actually relying on the data stored in a *primitive* type (which will of course be in some kind of base-2 representation).

Comment: Or possibly `CreateFromBinary(.....)`.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831342/97627) from @Reimeus, the various constructors for BigDecimal accept different types of input. The *floating point* constructors, take a floating point as input, and due to the limitations of the way that floats/doubles are stored, these can only store accurately values that are a power of 2.

So, for example, 2⁻², or 0.25, can be represented exactly. 0.875 is (2⁻¹ + 2⁻² + 2⁻³), so it can also be represented accurately. So long as the number can be represented by a sum of powers, where the upper and lower power differ by no more than 53, then the number can be represented exactly. The vast majority of numbers don't fit this pattern!

In particular, 0.15 is not a power of two, nor is it the sum of a power of two, and so the representation is not accurate.

The string constructor on the other hand does store it accurately, by using a different format internally to store the number. Hence, when you compare the two, they compare as being different.

Comment: More correctly, "integer multiples of powers of two". 0.75 can be represented exactly.

Comment: As long as the integer is < 2^53...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Fair enough… I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

What actually happens here is this:

- `0.015` is a primitive double. Which means that as soon as you write it, it is already no longer 0.015, but rather `0.0149...`. The *compiler* stores it as a binary representation in the bytecode.
- `BigDecimal` is constructed to store **exactly** whatever is given to it. In this case, `0.0149...`
- `BigDecimal` is also able to parse Strings into *exact* representations. In this case `"0.015"` is parsed into exactly `0.015`. Even though `double` cannot represent that number, `BigDecimal` can
- Finally, when you compare them, you can see that they are not equal. Which makes sense.

Whenever using `BigDecimal`, be cautious of the previously used type. `String`, `int`, `long` will remain exact. `float` and `double` have the usual precision caveat.